# Rhythmic tapping/banging sound on the external AC unit coupled with transformers in the furnace blowing out

Tags: furnace, noise, transformer

We have a strange issue.
We bought a house recently. We have several issues:

1. External AC unit keeps making banging sound when heat is on
2. The HVAC furnace stop functioning. In the last 6 months we have HVAC technician come out and replaced the transformer three times. The last time, the technician installed a 5-amp fuse on the low voltage side.
3. For the fourth time, the furnace stopped again, when I flipped from heat to cold. THe fuse is intact. I found that there is no output from the transformer to the control board. I replaced the transformer and for good measure changed the thermostat, but unit stopped functioning after half hour.

I read that a faulty contactor could be an issue. Given the loud banging noise from the external unit, could this be an issue?

Comment: Make and model of all hardware involved would be a good start, including the thermostat.

Comment: Not much sense replacing stuff unless you find the problem causing it.  Most transformers are usually long lasting.

Comment: but, but... @crip659, I _like_ randomly replacing parts!

Comment: If the banging is enough to get an audio recording that may help provide a path forward. Contactors are just a big relay and the larger ones do make a noise when the pull in, not as loud when they open. Reversing valves can make a noise but usually they are not loud. Has the starting cap been checked?